# How to access multiple virtual hosts in my localhost from my mobile phone/another machine

Tags: android, apache, networking, vhosts

I'm creating an android app that uses 2 virtual hosts. One for the api and one for the repository of all the images uploaded in my app. I can access one of them without using virtual hosts and through my laptop's IP address only. But I want to access them both through virtual hosts so that I dont have to change it when I upload it to the  live server. Please help me how to do it.

Here's the snippet of my XAMPP "httpd-vhosts.conf" file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myprojectapi"
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias api.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myimages"
    ServerName images.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias images.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and heres the snippet of my windows "hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1 api.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 images.mydomain.com
```

I can only access one of them from my android phone but only through my laptop's IP address and if i comment out one of the vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myprojectapi"
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias api.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myimages"
#    ServerName images.mydomain.com
#   ServerAlias images.mydomain.com
#</VirtualHost>
```

and my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 api.mydomain.com
#127.0.0.1 images.mydomain.com
```

but in order for my app to work properly i need to access the two projects through Named Virtual Hosts at the same time. What should I do to make this work? Please help.

**UPDATE:**

Im already using different ports but it still won't work.

Here's the snippet of my updated vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myprojectapi"
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias api.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myimages"
    ServerName images.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias images.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and heres the snippet in my updated hosts file:

```
192.168.2.5 api.mydomain.com
192.168.2.5 images.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Choose different ports.

Comment: 'But I want to access them both through virtual hosts'. Please explain exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: '127.0.0.1 api.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 images.mydomain.com'. Put the ip address of your laptop there. And that host file on your Android device. And use different ports.

Comment: What i mean is. I want to access them through "api.mydomain.com" and not through IP address.

Comment: I've already updated the question. please check if ive done it right.

Comment: @greenapps I've already used different ports but still I can only access them in my laptop and not in my android device/other laptop.

Comment: @YellowJ Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get access to your Virtual Hosts inside emulators (like GenyMotion or any other) follow bellow steps:

**1:** Open up `httpd.conf` file

**2:** Choose different ports for your different virtual hosts and make sure to add `Listen ****` there

```
Listen 80
Listen 8081

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myprojectapi"
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias api.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myimages"
    ServerName images.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias images.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**3:** Save the `httpd.conf` file and restart your `apache` services.

**4:** Open the browser in your emulator and go to `http://10.0.2.2:8081/`  you will see your `images.mydomain.com` there :)